# Navigation drawer with Navigation graph is not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph

I tried by creating a new project with Navigation drawer activity. Got autogenerated fragments with viewmodels. On clicking on the nav menu, it's not navigating to respective fragments.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

I verified the IDs in navigation graph with Navigation Menu, they are the same.
I'm new to Navigation graphs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Three years later, and Google still has not fixed this project template. Attempting to debug it shows just how overly complicated (and fragile) they made this navigation system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `activity_main` layout use

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

  <include/>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

instead of

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView/>

     <include/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The reason is in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout):

> To use a `DrawerLayout`, position your primary content view as the first child with width and height of `match_parent` and no `layout_gravity`>. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the `layout_gravity` appropriately. Drawers commonly use `match_parent` for height with a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This works. But it doesn't make any sense :/

Comment: I agree with you @shahal. It worked for me after days trying to make my NavigationView work with NavigationUI.

But this it's not mentioned anywhere, and also it's not documented. Jeez, someone can explain why this?

Anyway thank you so much Gabriele.

Comment: @FilipeBezerradeSousa I recently had a similar problem. Apparently, it is due to the reverse Z ordering in the XML. So if you define your DrawerLayout first, it actually is second in the Z order. It doesn't make much sense to me either, but I figured I might as well point out the term that guided me to the solution in case anyone else stumbles across this thread.

Comment: Thanks a lotttt. I created a new App, with Drawer, on Android Studio 4.1.2. With no a single change I was facing this issue.